# Houdini attribute mismatch on imported models

Tags: houdini

I received a warning when trying to merge 2 file loaded models:

> Warning
>
> A mis-match of attributes on the inputs was detected. Some attribute values may not be initialized to expected values, i.e.: N.

It appeared to be a problem of point and vertex attributes. Both models are created in and exported from Maya and one model has the normal in point attributes:

[image]

While the other model's normal is in vertex attributes:

[image]

What caused this an is there a way to fix it?